# How can I fix TypeErrors while downgrading Rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to use Ruby 1.8.7 and rubygems < 2.0 to work with an old application. When I attempt to downgrade the system rubygems to an older version I get this error:

```
$ sudo gem update --system 1.8.30
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    can't convert nil into String
```

My current ruby and gem versions:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin15.5.0]
$ gem --version
2.5.0
```

How can I fix this error (or get more information about what is causing the problem)?